# How To Handle Invalid Escape Sequences In Json That Has Some Valid Escape Sequences

Tags: json, .net, string

I need to parse json in .net that could contain both invalid escape sequences and valid ones:-

```
{ 
  "aField1": "this is an \n example of a value\", 
  "aField2": "this is another \t example of a \L value" 
}
```

When trying to parse or deserialise the above using something like json.net's JToken.Parse, an exception is thrown due to the presence of the two invalid escape sequences - `\"` and `\L`.

I don't think I need to escape the entire string as it has some valid escape sequences already, just handle the invalid ones (e.g. the `\` which has been added just before a legitimate closing quote, the `\` which has a letter after it that is not part of the valid escape character set like n, t, etc).

I can write something bespoke for this (and probably get it wrong!), but I was wondering if there is a way of using the usual .net json packages like json.net to deal with this particular scenario?

Comment: My experience of this sort of thing is that it's usually better to try to tackle the problem at its source. Where does the invalid JSON come from, and can you get *that* fixed?

Comment: yeah I 100% agree with that :) unfortunately the source (a third party) has to keep the problem in because it represents exactly what was typed in by a human. so I am stuck with having to deal with it on my end!

Comment: "unfortunately the source has to keep the problem in because it represents exactly what was typed in by a human" - that doesn't make sense to me. A human shouldn't be typing in JSON - or if they are, it should be rejected if it's not valid JSON. Fundamentally if you start escaping `\L` to mean "a backslash followed by an L" then it's really weird for `\n` to mean newline instead of "a backslash followed by an n".

Comment: apologies i should have been clearer, a human types in the value bit into some other system which accepts free text, then the system i get this data from collects that data and delivers it inside a json structure. i am not sure which system adds the \n, i don't think it is typed in by the human.

Comment: Right, so the component that "collects that data and delivers it inside JSON structure" should be providing valid JSON. `\L` is not valid JSON, and should not have been produced by that component. That component needs to be fixed. Who knows what other invalid JSON it'll produce? Will it fail to escape quotes, for example?

Comment: unfortunately that is the component owned by the third party so it won't be fixed :(

Comment: So how far are you willing to tolerate them producing broken JSON? How much data corruption will you try to work around? Producing valid JSON is really not hard - this sort of situation always makes me wonder what *other* problems their code has, particularly around security. I would complain to them really loudly...

Comment: (But I really wouldn't expect to find any JSON parser that's willing to tolerate arbitrary corruption like this. If you don't know whether `\"` is meant to be a backslash at the end of a string value or a double-quote within a string value, it's really hard to get any sensible behavior.)